# CSS - Setting the width of a span in % with respect to its maximum width

Tags: html, css, width

I have two divs containing text stacked over eachother. The bottom text is in grey and the top one in red. I'd like to be able to specify the % of the portion of my top red div that I want to display with CSS. When using `width: x%`, the % of the top div displayed is with respect to the whole line and not the content(text). I'd like to know the CSS fix needed to accomplish what I want.

http://jsfiddle.net/8oodus0n/

```
<div class="text-container">
    <span class="text-grey">
        We love Stack Overflow
    </span>
    <span class="text-color">
        We love Stack Overflow
    </span>
</div> 

.text-grey, .text-color{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.text-grey{
    color: grey;
}

.text-color{
    color: red;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 20%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to relatively position the parent `.text-container` element, then change the `display` to `inline-block`. In doing so, the width of the element will be determined by its contents, in this case the text. The width of the child span element will therefore respect the maximum width of the parent.

In order for this to work, only one of the `span` elements should be absolutely positioned. The reason for this is because absolutely positioned elements are essentially removed from the normal flow, thus the parent element's width is `0` if both elements are absolutely positioned. Therefore one of the elements needs to be normally positioned in order for the parent's width to be determined.

```
.text-color {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.text-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/y7rm1c7g/)

```
.text-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.text-grey, .text-color {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.text-grey {
    color: grey;
}
.text-color {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: red;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```